When runnig apt-add-repository retunrs /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceMalloc_NewReference
I've got an issue with python3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. Some utils like apt-add-repository are not working due to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceMalloc_NewReference. Any ideas how to solve it?
apt-add-repository 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 68, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceMalloc_NewReference


The default version of python on 20.04 is 3.8.2. If you changed that, you most likely broke your system.

python --version
Python 3.8.10. Any ideas have to solve this issue safely?

However: python3 --version
Python 3.10.14
